# MYSQL order by - NULL values impacting my results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, sql-order-by

A table of about 200 rows, 15 of which will have a numeric value rankClass (1-15). The rest will have NULL values.

`ORDER BY rankClass, nameLast`

It posts the rows with NULL values first, and when I add DESC, of course, it lists it set rows first, but 15-1.  I'd like it to list those with values first, 1-15, then the rest by nameLast.

I've tried coalesce, but it goes 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

How would I get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't see, why you ended up with a string sort by applying `COALESCE`. I am pretty sure, that something like `ORDER BY COALESCE(rankClass, 999)` will work just fine. I suppose you mistakenly used a string instead, i.e. something like `ORDER BY COALESCE(rankClass, '999')`. (A pity by the way, that MySQL does not support the standard SQL clause `ORDER BY ... NULLS LAST`, which would be the appropriate way to handle this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly check for `null`s in the `rankClass`, and order by an expression that moves them to the end:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY rankClass IS NULL, -- false comes before true
         rankClass
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I didn't one sample of that usage of IS NULL when I searched.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the sign of rankclass, you can then sort descending leaving the nulls at the end, e.g.

```
SELECT RankClass, NameLast
FROM T
ORDER BY -RankClass DESC, nameLast;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ebfe945a747cd3a5ad12cb6bf61761a)**